# How to tweak index_scan cost in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "routes_trackpoint"
WHERE "routes_trackpoint"."track_id" = 593
ORDER BY "routes_trackpoint"."id" ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Postgres is choosing a query plan which reads all the rows in the "id" index to perform the ordering, and them perform manual filtering to get the entries with the correct track id:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..511.22 rows=1 width=65) (actual time=4797.964..4797.966 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3388505
   ->  Index Scan using routes_trackpoint_pkey on routes_trackpoint  (cost=0.43..719699.79 rows=1409 width=65) (actual time=4797.958..4797.958 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (track_id = 75934)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 13005436
         Buffers: shared hit=3388505
 Total runtime: 4798.019 ms
(7 rows)
```

Disabling the index scan, the query plan (`SET enable_indexscan=OFF;`) is better and the response much faster.

```
Limit  (cost=6242.46..6242.46 rows=1 width=65) (actual time=77.584..77.586 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1075 read=6
   ->  Sort  (cost=6242.46..6246.64 rows=1674 width=65) (actual time=77.577..77.577 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=1075 read=6
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on routes_trackpoint  (cost=53.41..6234.09 rows=1674 width=65) (actual time=70.384..74.782 rows=1454 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (track_id = 75934)
               Buffers: shared hit=1075 read=6
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on routes_trackpoint_track_id  (cost=0.00..52.99 rows=1674 width=0) (actual time=70.206..70.206 rows=1454 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (track_id = 75934)
                     Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6
 Total runtime: 77.655 ms
(13 rows)
```

How can I get Postgres to select the better plan automatically?

I have tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE routes_trackpoint ALTER COLUMN track_id SET STATISTICS 5000;
ALTER TABLE routes_trackpoint ALTER COLUMN id SET STATISTICS 5000;
ANALYZE routes_trackpoint;
```

But the query plan remained the same.

The table definition is:

```
watchdog2=# \d routes_trackpoint
                                   Table "public.routes_trackpoint"
  Column  |           Type           |                           Modifiers                            
----------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer                  | not null default nextval('routes_trackpoint_id_seq'::regclass)
 track_id | integer                  | not null
 position | geometry(Point,4326)     | not null
 speed    | double precision         | not null
 bearing  | double precision         | not null
 valid    | boolean                  | not null
 created  | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "routes_trackpoint_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "routes_trackpoint_position_id" gist ("position")
    "routes_trackpoint_track_id" btree (track_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "track_id_refs_id_d59447ae" FOREIGN KEY (track_id) REFERENCES routes_track(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

PS: We have forced postgres to sort by "created" instead, which also helped him use the index on "track_id".

Comment: Does `"routes_trackpoint"."id"` come from a sequence ?

Comment: `ORDER BY "routes_trackpoint"."id" ASC` and the primary key is routes_trackpoint.id ? (please add table definitions, etc)

Comment: BTW: `LIMIT1 ` is terrible. You could use a row_number() over (ORDER BY id) or a not exists() instead.

Comment: What's the value of [`random_page_cost`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-RANDOM-PAGE-COST). If you constantly see index scans are faster than seq scans and the planner always prefers the seq scan, you might want to think about lowering `random_page_cost`

Comment: @wildplasser I have added the table definiton in the post.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The value is 4

Comment: If you have a fast harddisk (e.g. a SSD) or if chances are that a lot of indexes are cached, you might want to try lowering that value. 2.5 might be a good place to start. But beware: this affects **all** queries you should check if this doesn't affect other queries negatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `LIMIT` as much as you can.
Plan #1: use `NOT EXISTS()` to get the first one

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM routes_trackpoint tp
WHERE tp.track_id = 593
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM routes_trackpoint nx
        WHERE nx.track_id = tp.track_id AND nx.id < tp.id
        );
```

---

Plan #2: use row_number() OVER *some_window* to get the first one of the group.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT tp.*
FROM routes_trackpoint tp
JOIN (select track_id, id
        , row_number() OVER (partition BY track_id ORDER BY id) rn
        FROM routes_trackpoint tp2
        ) omg ON omg.id = tp.id
WHERE tp.track_id = 593
AND omg.rn = 1
        ;
```

---

Or -even better- move the WHERE clause to the subquery :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT tp.*
FROM routes_trackpoint tp
JOIN (select track_id, id
        , row_number() OVER (partition BY track_id ORDER BY id) rn
        FROM routes_trackpoint tp2
        WHERE tp2.track_id = 593
        ) omg ON omg.id = tp.id
WHERE 1=1
-- AND tp.track_id = 593
AND omg.rn = 1
        ;
```

---

Plan#3 use the postgres-specific `DISTINCT ON()` construct (thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name):

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT DISTINCT ON (track_id) track_id, id
FROM routes_trackpoint tp2
WHERE tp2.track_id = 593
-- order by track_id, created desc
order by track_id, id
        ;
```

Comment: Third option: `distinct on()` which is usually faster than a solution using window functions.

Comment: I don't think that will work here. The OP needs the *oldest* record, which implies some kind of order.

Comment: `row_Number()` also implies some kind of order. The same order can be used for `distinct on ()`, something like: http://pasted.co/e59f691b

Comment: It appears to work. (BTW the `created` field is not part of a key. `(track_id, created)` *could* be a natural key, I agree.) I'll add your suggestion to the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed queries @wildplasser . I have run them on the database, and am incluing their query plans in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/C3HrinQd). Please, feel free to copy the query plans below each recommendations, I think it can be of great use to others.

Comment: Btw, I think this is a great piece of information, but the original question was actually: "How can I get Postgres to select the better plan automatically?" and not how to rewrite the query. Interestingly, after running a slightly different query for a day (order by 'created' instead of 'id') postgres has also started using a better query plan for the original query. (Both query plans are included in the pastebin above).

Comment: You get the better plan by not lying to the optimiser. 0) know your data and its distribution; maybe usage. 1) prefer FKs to loose indices, add UNIQUE constraints where appropiate 2) add a supporting index for the FK (if not already present). 3) (maybe) add additional indices for the hard hitting queries. 4) set tuning constants {concurrent_sessions,random_page_cost, work_mem, expected_cache_size, shared_buffers} to sane values. 6) LIMIT is evil. 6) check the plan.